# More efficient than acc.reverse ::: b?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm tail optimizing a recursive function. At the end, the result will be `acc.reverse ::: b`. This is O(n) because of `reverse` and `:::`. Is there a better performance way to combine the two lists? Thanks.

Ex. Combine `List(3, 2, 1)` and  `List(4, 5, 6)` to `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library includes the `reverse_:::` method for this:

```
scala> List(3, 2, 1) reverse_::: List(4, 5, 6)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

This is still O(n), but avoids the separate call to `:::`.

---

Just for the sake of fun and learning, you could easily implement this as  a tail-recursive function:

```
@tailrec
def reverseConcat[A](lefts: List[A], rights: List[A]): List[A] =
  lefts match {
    case Nil => rights
    case head::tail => reverseConcat(tail, head::rights)
  }
```

Or using `foldLeft`:

```
def reverseConcat[A](lefts: List[A], rights: List[A]): List[A] =
  lefts.foldLeft(rights)((xs, x) => x :: xs)
```

Note that `reverse_:::` is not implemented using tail-recursion; it uses a `var` behind the scenes, so might perform differently.

Comment: ha, very neat method from the api. It does it in one pass, and even states it's more efficient in the doc.